# How to source inside proc?

Tags: tcl

There is a code which generate the file with one proc:

```
puts $fh "proc generate \{ fileName\} \{"
puts $fh "[info body generateScriptBody]"
puts $fh "\}"
puts $fh "generate"
close $fh

proc generateScriptBody{} {
    source something1    
    source something2 
    ...
}
```

In this case should I `source` inside proc or there are alternatives?

Comment: Does this code work or not? There's no issue with putting source inside a proc.

Comment: [glenn jackman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) No there no any issue. I just wondered is it good practice to source inside proc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what you are trying to do, but source within a proc is acceptable. If you are looking to write the whole proc into a file, take a look at `saveprocs` from the TclX package; it will help simplifying your code.

#### Update

Here is an example of using `saveprocs`:

```
package require Tclx

# Generate a proc from body of one or more files
set body [read_file something1]
append body "\n" [read_file something2]
proc generate {fileName} $body

# Write to file
saveprocs generate.tcl generate
```

In this case, I did away with all the `source` commands and read the contents directly into the proc's body.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered a problem with calling source inside a proc, maybe it's helpful for someone.

I have two test files. This is `sourcetest1.tcl` which sources `sourcetest2.tcl` in three different ways:

```
puts "sourcetest1.tcl"

proc mysource_wrong {script} {
    source $script
}

proc mysource_right {script} {
    uplevel "source sourcetest2.tcl"
}

#source sourcetest2.tcl
#mysource_right sourcetest2.tcl
mysource_wrong sourcetest2.tcl
```

This is `sourcetest2.tcl`:

```
puts "sourcetest2.tcl"

set l {1 2 3}

puts "outside: $l"

proc doit {} {
    global l
    puts "doit: $l"
}

doit
```

Everything is fine with a direct `source` and with `mysource_right`, the output is in both cases:

```
sourcetest1.tcl
sourcetest2.tcl
outside: 1 2 3
doit: 1 2 3
```

However, with `mysource_wrong`, we get the following output:

```
sourcetest1.tcl
sourcetest2.tcl
outside: 1 2 3
can't read "l": no such variable
    while executing
"puts "doit: $l""
    (procedure "doit" line 3)
    invoked from within
"doit"
    (file "sourcetest2.tcl" line 12)
    invoked from within
"source $script"
    (procedure "mysource_wrong" line 2)
    invoked from within
"mysource_wrong sourcetest2.tcl"
    (file "sourcetest1.tcl" line 13)
```

My interpretation is that a `source` inside a `proc` puts the variable `l` into the scope of the `proc`, not into the global scope. This can be avoided by using `uplevel` like in `mysource_right`.